# Hide SQLite Database in Android from Other Applications

Tags: android, sqlite, security

I am Working on an Android Application which will be launched with a huge Pre loaded SQLite database. Problem is that database is visible to Applications like HACKDataApp etc. And Can also be viewed and copied in Android Device Monitor.
Question is, Is there any way to protect\hide my database from other applications??

Comment: by chance did u get any feasible solution? Can you please share with me if you find any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

you got to make your contentProvider not exported. SImply as that :

from official documentation :
android:exported: Flag allowing other applications to use this provider.

put this in your manifest declaration for each contentProvider.

Comment: Note though that it will still not be secure. Applications simply must not have hard-coded secrets in any form, be it actual code or a sqlite db distributed with the app. Anything that's on the client is controlled by the client, you can't protect any data from users if it's on their device.

Comment: Yes, i was not saying that is totally secure, just not available for other apps. Here he just asked to hide his database to other apps. To my mind, the best approach for persisting data is Realm.io now, providing a real good encryption process and faster / better use than sqlite for dev.

Comment: @mcfly, can you please tell me what exactly need to be included in manifest to not show or cannot be exported of my sqlite database?

Comment: @Uday https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported here you have complete official documentation to do it